# Wrong output with openssl_decrypt in PHP instead of what expected AES 128 ECB

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I'm having an hexadecimal string in input that for test purposes is

```
$encryptedText = "4181EF4A4690BC0B1281355489C96009"; // Plain text expected == "c704774b4a2f7080280000f5a5d104a8"
```

I've encrypted that text with AES 128 EBC and now i need to decrypt that in PHP to manage datas.
That's what i do:

```
$key = "0000000000000000";
$method = "aes-128-ecb";
$encryptedText = hex2bin($encryptedText);
$decryptedText = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText,$method,$key,3);
var_dump($decryptedText);
echo "<br>";
var_dump(bin2hex($decryptedText));
```

The openssl_decrypt function returns these Hexadecimal string: 03ddffd8bfb08a6c9b908f86cdf5536c instead of the one expected.
Using the following online tool i can get the right answer: http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/

So my question is what am i doing wrong ? Did i miss something in the usage of openssl_decrypt?

EDIT:

Thanks to [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) i've understood that my mistake was the key format so i've added that line of code
`$key = hex2bin($key);`
Now everything works.

Comment: The online tool returns the same plaintext as the PHP code.  Depends of course on the options set on the website, which you have not posted, just like the expected plaintext.

Comment: Ok, basically i'm using the key as plaintext instead of using the key as HEX value like i'm doing on the website (sorry if i've not posted the configuration used on the website). The configuration is: input type -> text as HEX value; function AES as ECB and key as HEX value

Comment: Oh also the expected plaintext is the one in the comment just to the right of the encrypted text, i'm going to edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: Note that the current key is hex decoded only 8 bytes and thus too short. PHP (and also the online tool) extend the too short key by silently padding with 0x00 values to the required length of 16 bytes for AES 128. However, most applications do not implicitly fix keys and only accept valid keys.